# Can you permanently mark or write on a tire?

Tags: tires

In [another question](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/67289/how-much-to-inflate-essentially-unlabeled-tires) I figured out how to get some basic info on my poorly labelled trailer tires.

Now that I know the inflation pressure, load rating, etc., I'd like to write this on the tire in some way, ideally permanently. I don't want to go from memory long after when I need to check the pressure (nor avoid doing it because I'm unsure of the right values).

Is there any way to safety and effectively write (or paint?) on a tire?

Comment: Is there somewhere on the wheel you can permanently mark it? Is there a tool box of some type on the trailer? You can paste something on the inside of the box which would have the information on it ... or anywhere inconspicuous. Really, the tire isn't the place to put it, for two reasons: 1) it won't stay there; 2) if you change the tires, you have to do it again.

Comment: Writing it on the wheel or chassis of the trailer is a safer bet as it won't be subject to wear and it'll outlive the tyre itself.  There are plenty places online which will make you up a tyre pressure table or use a stencil to paint it on to make it neat.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's nothing you can do to reliably and safely mark the tires because it's such a harsh environment. They're being spun hundreds or thousands of times per minute, blasted by wind constantly and exposed to heat, cold, dirt, salt (in some places), rain, ice, and sun. A sharpie just isn't going to last, and any sticker will go sooner or later no matter how well they are glued on. This is the reason tires are marked by raised material or impressions in the material - it's the only way they'll last.

Cutting into the material of the sidewall is an option, but not a good one as you could weaken the tire and cause a blowout, your best bet is to put the information someplace it can be referred to on the trailer or the car, someplace protected from the elements.